# generate comments for function by emacs

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

The function :

```
function show($string = "hi") {
    echo $string;
}
```

I need the comments like:

```
/**
* @brief 
* 
* @param $string
*
* @returns
*/

function show($string = "hi") {
    echo $string;
}
```

Can I generate comments like this by yasnippet?

In vim, doxygentoolkit can do it.

Whitch tool i can use in emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Doxymacs](http://doxymacs.sourceforge.net/).  It hasn't been updated in a while, but still works for me.